# Localize global namsapce in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, global

I have a Javascript structure like below and it's about 8000 lines of code long:

```
var abc = {
  test: function(){
    abc.xyz()
  },

  testAbc : function(){
   abc.123()
  },

 testxyz : function(){
   abc.qws()
 },

}
```

I don't want to repeat `abc` before every function call. Is this possible?

Comment: How does jQuery tie in here? Seems like a "plain" JavaScript question to me. Is your objection to `abc` that you don't want to have the body of the object tied to the variable it is assigned to, in which case you could probably use `this` instead? Or you just don't want the extra characters and want to use the function names directly?

Comment: yep I don't want any extra character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> jQuery.extend(window, abc);

This solution requires jQuery.